# MS Access 07 - wildcard in JOIN query

Tags: join, ms-access-2007

I've got the following query

```
SELECT tblUsers.userfullname, 
       tblReports.reportdate, 
       tblReports.reportnumber, 
       tblRawData.reportcategory, 
       tblRawData.reportissue
FROM tblRawData 
RIGHT JOIN (tblUsers RIGHT JOIN tblReports ON tblUsers.userID = tblReports.userID) ON tblReports.reportnumber LIKE "*" & tblRawData.reportnum
WHERE (
       ((tblUsers.username) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSelect]![txtUser] & "*") 
       AND
       ((tblUsers.userShift) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSelect]![txtShift] & "*")
      );
```

Which works - except the part of

```
ON tblReports.reportnumber LIKE "*" & tblRawData.reportnum
```

what i'm trying to match is instances where

```
tblReports.reportnumber = 410145
```

and

```
tblRawData.reportnum = 12345.410145
```

or just

```
tblRawDatw.reportnum = 410145
```

but for some reason it just will not find that first match (ex: 12345.410145) unless the number is identical like the second match (ex: 410145).  I've tried formatting it as a number as well as text - and no luck.

any idea what I may be missing?

Update:  I tried making another query with just the two tables and it doesn't like to match.  i tried removing the "." (example: 12345.410145 into 12345410145) and no luck.  here's my second query.

```
SELECT tblReports.userID, 
tblRawData.reportnum,
tblRawData.reportcategory,
tblRawData.reportissue,
tblReports.reportdate,
tblReports.reportnumber
FROM tblReports
LEFT JOIN tblRawData ON tblReports.reportnumber LIKE "*" & tblRawData.reportnum;
```

where if the data is like such.

tblReports Report numbers:
410145
410144
410143
410142
410141

and tblRawData report numbers are such:
12345.410145
410143
12344.410141

the resulting query should show me all 5 records from tblReports - but three of those records have the notes and such from tblRawData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewritten to allow for no match.

```
SELECT 
   u.userfullname, 
   r.reportdate, 
   r.reportnumber, 
   q.reportcategory, 
   q.reportissue
FROM (tblusers u 
LEFT JOIN tblreports r 
ON u.userid = r.userid) 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
      Val(Mid([reportnum],InStr([reportnum],".")+1)) AS RepNo, 
      r.reportcategory, 
      r.reportissue
   FROM Rawdata AS r)  AS q
ON r.reportnumber = q.RepNo
AND q.username  Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSelect]![txtUser] & "*"
AND q.userShift Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSelect]![txtShift] & "*"
```

It is a common enough convention that LEFT JOINs are used rather than RIGHT JOINs.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - got held up by Hurricane Sandy.  for this no luck, it gives me all records from rawdata that match and none from reports that do not also exist in rawdata - and the rawdata matches seems to ignore the wildcard also.

Comment: The no matched records need to be included as `Or d.reportnumber Is Null` I will get back to you on the wildcard. ( I hope you and yours are safe, and keep safe )

Comment: Okay, the match is just the wrong way around. That is `(tblRawData.reportnum) 12345.410145 LIKE (reportnumber) * & 410145`

Comment: No luck, I tried both d.reportnum Is Null and r.reportnumber Is Null to the same effect

Comment: Okay, I have posted a completely different approach. it could be slow.

Comment: Error of "Join expression not supported"

Comment: Revised and tested. Formatting neatly can be a pain :)

Comment: i'm just at a loss with it.  I created two queries hitting each individual table and they find what I'm looking for no problem - but try to use one table's record to lookup another table's - forget it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18792/discussion-between-remou-and-chasester)

Comment: well i'll be - it works!.   so it's obviously in the VAL/InStr statements.  any idea why it wouldn't have worked when I had both fields set to numeric?

Comment: The problem was with getting the no matches. If you had just wanted matches, the wildcard would have been fine. If you use LIKE, it casts the fields as text, so numeric is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check everything, but I have some ideas. Maybe you have to swap the LIKE condition?

```
tblRawData.reportnum LIKE "*" & tblReports.reportnumber
```

if that's not the problem, could you try to use the `trim` function?

```
Trim(tblReports.reportnumber) LIKE "*" & Trim(tblRawData.reportnum)
```

Answer (score -1):

The wildcard character for SQL queries is the percent sign '%' not the asterisk.  Try using that instead.  But if you are including every match then why have that in your query at all?

[Access wildcard character reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HA010076601.aspx)

Comment: ANSI-89 is the type - so it's *.  I'm not understanding your question on including every match.

Comment: What I mean is that if you are including all matches why is it in your where clause?  For a simpler example: `select * from table where i like '*'` you don't need the where clause.

Comment: I am afraid this answer is not right for MS Access without a lot more explanation. The wildcard when working in MS Access using the default ANSI settings is *, working with the Jet/ACE engine and ADO outside of Access or with SQL Server compatible settings inside of MS Access (ANSI92), the wildcard is %. It would appear that Chasester is working inside of MS Access, so the wildcard is indeed *.

Comment: Yes the '*' appears to work in MS Access.  Sorry for the confusion.